# Ajax chuncked gzip with php in Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer, gzip

This code works fine chrome and firefox but not in IE, data comes compressed:

```
    $output_compressed = gzencode($output_json);
    $splitString = str_split($output_compressed, 1024);
    header("Content-type: application/javascript; charset: UTF-8");
    header('Content-Length: ' . (string)strlen($output_compressed));
    header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    header('Connection: keep-alive');
    header('Transfer-Encoding: gzip');

    foreach($splitString as $chunk) {
        echo $chunk;
        flush();
    }
```

The ajax part:

```
xhr = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getJSON.php",
                data: postData,
                    success: function(data){...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm using HHVM, by the way.